# Get url of php file that execute phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I need to get url of php file that execute phantomjs and put fragment (hash) into php variable.
I mean get URL of current php file that phantomjs is execute like this: examle.com/need_url_of_this_page.php#11111

Comment: Looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php (for the PHP side, who's doing the requesting doesn't really matter in this case)

Comment: NO, I need the fragment parameter. I need to put hash in php variable.

Comment: url hash doesn't get sent to server, it's only maintained by browser